# Filling numpy array using [:,:] crashes python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, crash, numpy

Greetings,

I have come across an interesting error and was wondering if anyone knew the cause.

I create several numpy arrays of dtype object and wish to initialize them with empty strings, so I did the following to create them:

```
txtInputs=empty((7,12), dtype=object)
txtInputs[:, :]=''

repeated...
```

How they are used after is not relevant other than that these variables are local to the function and are gone when it returns.  However, I have discovered that when I call the function that does this many times in a row, my program crashes with an error saying pythonw.exe has stopped working.  This crash is consistent and happens after a specific number of calls, and that number never changes.

However, if I replace the second line with:

```
txtInputs.fill('')
```

It will not crash.  What is wrong with using [:,:]='' to fill the numpy array??

Thank you.

PS.  I am using python 2.5 and numpy 1.0.4

Comment: Just a note, sometimes it gives me a C++ Runtime Library error and other times it just says pythonw.exe has stopped working.  So it does seem to point to windows only...

Comment: I asked mainly out of curiosity -- there have been 9 NumPy releases since 1.0.4.  Another reason for asking is that I don't have access to such an old version of NumPy, so I can't reproduce your problem.  If this is a NumPy problem, chances are it has been fixed meanwhile, but I don't know if it is a NumPy problem.

Answer (score 4):

This error does not occur with numpy 1.5.1. We were fixing quite a few bugs around the time of numpy 1.0.4, particularly with the object and string dtypes. This is probably one of them. The bug has apparently been fixed since then.